# Getting all let bindings of module with reflection

Tags: reflection, f#

I've tried to get all let binding fields of an F# module but am struggling.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
|> Seq.collect(fun t -> t.GetFields())
```

but it doesn't seem to return the bindings. (the code is abbreviated and the types are only modules)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want just the `let` bindings and not any types defined inside the module, you can use the following filters on the module type members:

```
open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

module Test =
    type Marker = interface end

    let x = 3

    let f x = x * x

    let m = List.map


let moduleType = typeof<Test.Marker>.DeclaringType

moduleType.GetMembers()
|> Array.filter (fun m -> m.DeclaringType = moduleType)
|> Array.filter (fun m -> m.IsDefined(typeof<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>, true) |> not)
|> Array.filter (fun m -> m.MemberType <> MemberTypes.NestedType)
|> Array.map (fun m -> m.Name)
```

This will give you back:  `[|"f"; "m"; "x"|]`